# how to run JMeter load test and JMeter Webdriver test in paralle

Tags: jmeter, webdriver

I want to do browser based load testing with JMeter.This I can achieve by using web diver sampler and a thread group with multiple concurrent users. This limits me to test only with about 10 users as opening more browser instances eats away my system resources.My objective is to see how the GUI behaves when the server is under heavy load (say 1000) users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [Web Driver Tutorial](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverTutorial/)

> Note: It is NOT the intention of this project to replace the HTTP Samplers included in JMeter. Rather it is meant to compliment them by measuring the end user load time.

So you should not be creating the main load using the WebDriver Sampler, you can use it in another [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) in parallel with the main load conducted by the [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers to measure page rendering speed, catch any markup or JavaScript errors, etc.

Well-behaved JMeter virtual user looks just like a real user using the real browser from backend perspective so make sure you properly mimic real user behavior, to wit:

- "embedded resources" handling (images, scripts, styles, fonts, etc.)

  [image: JMeter Embedded Resources]
- [cache](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager)
- [headers](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager)
- [cookies](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager)
- ["think times"](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#timers)

Check out [How to make JMeter behave more like a real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser) for more details.

Comment: Thanks Dmitri, is there any specific setting to run HTTP Request Sampler and Webdriver Sampler in parallel?

Comment: No rocket science, just add 2 Thread groups: one for HTTP request samplers and another one for WebDriver, they will be executed in parallel

Comment: Hi Dmitri, I am using Webdriver sampler with JavaScript. Is it possible to use external code in a sampler? I have many samplers which use almost same code. I want to write this code in an external file and call the required methods (with appropriate arguments) in multiple samplers. If it is not possible then is there a way to call a sampler from within another sampler?

Answer (score 0):

This is the case to work with [Remove/Distributed Testing](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html)

> Note: The same test plan is run by all the servers. JMeter does not distribute the load between servers, each runs the full test plan. So if you set 1000 Threads and have 6 JMeter server, you end up injecting 6000 Threads.

So in your case if you have 100 JMeter servers each will execute 10 users opening browser.